# Distance matrix limitations on a Freemium HERE Developper plan

Tags: routes, here-api

For an academic project, I'm trying to generate a distance matrix approximatively containing 160K entries (around 50 origins * 3000 destinations) using HERE Matrix Routing API v8 with an Asynchronous Request and Profile Mode.

My dashboard says I have used 9 out of 250K free monthly transactions, but when I submit my request I receive the following response in return:

```json
{
    "title": "insufficient permissions",
    "status": 403,
    "code": "E601110",
    "cause": "forbidden: your current plan is limited to requests of size up to 15 origins and 100 destinations (max. 15x100), or 100 origins and 1 destination (max. 100x1)",
    "action": "Please contact support for more information.",
    "correlationId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

The `cause` property is pretty explicit, but I can't see the corresponding limitation listed on HERE website and as the total number of transactions of this request is below my available limit, I'd like to know what needs to be done in order to get sufficient permissions and to generate this distance matrix with a single request?

Comment: Hi Tolga, I'm a developer advocate working with the Matrix Routing team and I'd love to get your feedback (beyond the pricing issue that you came across). If you are open to having a chat, I'd appreciate it if you could reach out to me: https://twitter.com/sainaparsi

Comment: Hi Sayna, thank you for reaching out. It turns out I'm far from being a great tweeter, so I'd rather send an e-mail to the address mentioned in your Stack Overflow profile. Talk to you soon!

Answer (score 1):

A Freemium account can request only small matrices from the Matrix Routing API, up to 15x100 matrix sizes and up to 100x1.

Above these matrix sizes, it is not free, you have to update to Pro plan ($449/month or 449€/month).

You are correct, HERE's website does not clearly mention this restriction, maybe because this change in the license took effect on October 2020.

Comment: So this is regardless of settings? I.e. No matter the profile?

Comment: Yep, regardless of the settings